# How to upload a ebook to google play book from my app?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I want to access Google play books app from my E-books collection app. Currently I'm using FBReader to open selected E-book from my app.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/epub");
ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android", "org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.FBReader");
intent.setComponent(cn);
```

But now i want to upload ebook to play books to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mine type for EPub is **"application/epub+zip"**, from a Fragment use 
`getActivity().startActivity(i)` to start Google Play Book also `startActivity(i)`.

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(aBook.mProductFileName), "application/epub+zip");
getActivity().startActivity(i);
```

You can use `MimeTypeMap` to detect the Minetype

```
MimeTypeMap myMime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
String mimeType = myMime.getMimeTypeFromExtension("file_ext");
```

Comment: Hi Khaleel, I wonder if you were able to upload epub or pdf file from your app into google play book to read in google play book. I am looking for same thing in xamarin.android though. Can you please provide some lines of codes here. Thank you.